# When i click on generate csv, in excel sheet column am giving a no. with decimal point xx.00 but 00 are missing in csv file

Tags: excel, csv, vba

I have a column in excel sheet where am entering a number restricted to 2 decimal points. When I enter 12.33 and generate csv file. Am getting number as 12.33 but if I enter 12.00 and generate csv file. Am getting number as 12. Why it is happening ? Even in advanced options I have set to show zero's. Any help on this ?

Comment: CSV files store content not format.

Comment: You may be misinterpreting your problem.  What do you see if you open your `CSV` file with `NotePad`?  If you open it in Excel, you will see just a `12`; but if you open it in NotePad, you will see the `12.00`. In general, you should be `IMPORT`ing `csv` files so that you can control the format before it reaches Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Select the cells you want do export
- Right click
- Format cells
- Select the decimal places you want
- Export again

Comment: Its not accepting the format or is not exporting decimal places? This option is on up down button on right. Can you try open exported csv with notpad and check if the value is correct?

Comment: not exporting decimal values properly, for example if i give 12.22 it is taking but if i give 12.00 then in csv file zero's are not present. Csv it will be like 12 but for 12.22 in csv it is 12.22 only

Comment: opened csv on notepad?

Comment: I Think that is your problem https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/611af71f-d72b-4df6-b197-8930185b7fda/losing-decimal-places-when-exporting-to-csv?forum=exceldev